# find string inside files in a dir then copy them

Tags: linux, centos

i am running centos and have found similar questions, however no one needs to do exactly what i do.

I want to find a string inside any file reclusivly inside of:

> /home/username/mail/.person1\@someemaildir_com/

as it finds them or after it finds them, COPY any file that it found to another folder here:

> /home/username/mail/.person2\@someemaildir_com/.Mail\ Folder/

Here is what i tried without it working:

```
grep -lir 'stringtofind' /home/username/mail/.person1\@someemaildir_com/* | xargs cp -t /home/username/mail/.person2\@someemaildir_com/.Mail\ Folder/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone else looking for this answer. i switched tactics and got the below working very well.

```
find /home/username/mail/.person1\@someemaildir_com/  -name '*' -exec grep -l "string to find" {} \; -exec cp {} /home/username/mail/.person2\@someemaildir_com/.Mail\ Folder/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose following (assuming your `grep "stringtofind"` does what it should do):

```
grep -lir "stringtofind" /home/username/mail/.person1\@someemaildir_com/* | while read f; do
    cp "$f" /home/username/mail/.person2\@someemaildir_com/.Mail\ Folder/
done
```

" around $f may be important because of blanks in file- or folder-names

Comment: Hi Leu, Thanks for the suggestion. It doesnt work. It just sits there as if its doing something. But does do anything.     :(

Comment: Hmm, difficult to say... - try to replace the content of the do-loop to `echo "would copy $f to  /home/username/mail/.person2\@someemaildir_com/.Mail\ Folder/"` - maybe you can break down the problem this way

Comment: Thank you Leu, i ended up getting it to work. I changed tactics and switched to find instead of grep. I just answered my own question below.

Comment: Just to make things clear: Are the files you're interested in within hidden directories like `.Mail Folder`? Then `*` isn't expanded to these, instead one has to write something like `grep -lir "stringtofind" /home/username/mail/.person1\@someemaildir_com/.[A-z]*`